# Functional language with C-like syntax

Tags: c, functional-programming, static-typing, lua

I've been looking for functional language with C-like syntax and static typing. So far my choice would be [Nemerle](http://nemerle.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page). Is there anything else/better?

EDIT:

second choice would be Lua or Go.

Any pros and cons?

Comment: I think you should specify which features you are interested in, behind static typing.

Comment: I will not be using it in a project (at least for now). I want to learn functional programming with the language as a platform. It has to be mature enough, running on windows. Would be great to have interactive mode. Also, not very complicated.

Comment: The mention of lua and go here is bizarre.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general functional languages do not have C like syntax, It comes down to the fact that functional languages do things differently than C type languages so the syntax tends to be very different (and often shorter). At least for me adopting to the new syntax has not been a big deal when picking up languages. Right now I'm spending most of my time on Erlang but also took a look at Haskell and have done scheme in the past.

Comment: I do think for some the syntax is wildly different and that can be scary. Although, after a day or two looking at Lisp I can say that I absolutely love the syntax. Sometimes it is better to just break out of ones comfort zone!

Comment: yep but Lisp has very weak type system.

Comment: True, but take say Haskell, which has a crazy strong type system, its got its own ideas on on syntax but it kind of grows on you.

Comment: @lukas - Like Zachary said, I'm more stating the fact that the syntax will grow on you after awhile, but only if  you give it a chance.

Comment: @lukas:  Common Lisp has a strong type system.  All objects are typed, and the type is determinable in detail at any time.  You may be thinking that it has a dynamic, not static, type system.

Comment: @David I disagree. Theoreticly, type checking has nothing to do with type system. We have dynamic languages with weak typing(Lisp) and stronger(Phyton). An example: expresson  + 3 "aa" works for Lisp but it is semantic error for Phyton(3 + 'aa'), because Phyton **checks** the types of this expresson. Similary with static typing(typing at compile time), but I guess such thing does not exist(language with static type system and weak type checking).

Comment: @lukas: C has static,weak type; C++ is even weaker (and 'staticker' too).

Comment: @Javier what do you mean by weak? runtime type checking?

Comment: @lukas:  What the heck version of Lisp are you using?  I specified Common Lisp, because I don't like generalizing across language families, and I'm not all that familiar with Scheme or Emacs lisp.  To repeat, Common Lisp is strongly dynamically typed.

Comment: @lukas: no, runtime type is dynamic type.  weak means that values convert from one type to another automatically.  strong type means that any conversion has to be explicit.

Answer (score 9):

I would say JavaScript

- It is a functional language
- It uses C syntax
- It can be used on a variety of operating systems (in both client and server mode), can be embedded in a lot of platforms (.NET, Java, Qt )

  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145053/javascript-as-a-functional-language) can be useful.

Answer (score 5):

Scala has a distinctly C like syntax, albeit with an Object-oriented layer on top which comes via Java.  The language is a nice blend of functional programming in the Standard ML family with an object-oriented language whose type system is tightly built into the ML-style static type inferencer of the language.

This means that you can type inference and pattern match over objects of user-defined classes in configurable ways, while keeping the strong-typedness which the ML-family languages are known for.

That said, I'd agree with the other posters -- consider stretching yourself a little more;  learn a lisp, which is to say a language which is almost without syntax, and you'll never be hung up on `which' syntax your next language has again.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Single Assignment C](http://www.sac-home.org/) is the first that comes to mind.

However, I agree with the others. The syntax of functional languages can often be the interesting part! For instance, you can [embed BASIC syntax inside Haskell's](http://augustss.blogspot.com/2009/02/more-basic-not-that-anybody-should-care.html)!

Answer (score 0):

For you purposes (from the second comment) you should pick a language as little similar to C as possible, IMHO. Prolog and Scheme are best match to you requirements (except C-style syntax, of cause).

Anyway, you should keep in mind that all languages in your list are general-purpose and industry-oriented. They are not intended to be used for learning.